# Изменение таблицы mysql с помощью php запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Я пытался написать скрипт, чтобы когда форма отправлялась, в базе заменялся параметр **money** название базы **users**. 
Я сделал примерчик, чтобы считал, на сколько заменять.
Проблема в том, что не заменяет он ничего.

```
<?php  
/* Соединяемся с базой данных */
$hostname = "localhost"; // название/путь сервера, с MySQL
$username = "name"; // имя пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию "root")
$password = "pass"; // пароль пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию пароль отсутствует, этот параметр можно оставить пустым)
$dbName = "db_name"; // название базы данных

/* Создаем соединение */
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");

/* Выбираем базу данных. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее */
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());
$s = $userinfo["money"];
$y = 100;
$x = $s-$y;

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money='".$x."' WHERE login=".$userinfo["login"]);

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?
/*!!!Чтобы не повредить работоспособности 
    скрипта выше этого комментария 
    не размещайте вообще ничего!!!*/
include('connectdb.php');// подключение к серверу MySql и выбор БД
$userinfo='';
$state='0';
if( (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) & (isset($_COOKIE['pass'])) ) {// если в куках лежит логин и зашифрованый пароля
  if (!isset($_GET['exit'])) {// если кнопка выход не была нажата
    $login=$_COOKIE['login'];
    $pass=$_COOKIE['pass'];

    // проверяем наличие пользователя в БД и достаём оттуда пароль
    $sql="SELECT id, pass FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){// если пользователь есть в БД
      $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($res);// в этой переменной лежит пароль из БД
      if(strcmp($pass,md5($userinfo['pass'])) == 0) { //проверяем схожесть пароля из БД с паролем из куков

    // достаём все данные из БД
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    $userinfo=mysql_fetch_array($res); // в этой переменной будет лежать вся информация о пользователе из БД
    $time=time();
    // устанавливаем куки для запоминания статуса пользователя
    setcookie("login",$login,$time+1800);
    setcookie("pass",$pass,$time+1800);
    $state = 1;// статус, если 1, тогда пользователь авторизован
      }
    }
  } else {
    //обнуляем куки, если была нажата кнопка выход
    setcookie("login");
    setcookie("pass");
  }
}
if($state != 1) {// если после проверки куков, оказалось, что пользователь не авторизован, то идем дальше
  if( (isset($_POST['login'])) & (isset($_POST['pass'])) ){ // если пользователь ввёл логин и пароль
  $login = $_POST['login'];    

  // проверяем наличие пользователя в БД и достаём оттуда пароль
  $sql = "SELECT id, pass FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0) {// если пользователь есть в БД
      $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($res);// в этой переменной лежит пароль из БД и номер пользователя
      $pass = $_POST['pass'];
      if(strcmp($pass,$userinfo['pass'])==0){

    // достаём все данные из БД
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    $userinfo=mysql_fetch_array($res);// в этой переменной будет лежать вся информация о пользователе из БД
    $time=time();
    // устанавливаем куки для запоминания статуса пользователя, пароль шифруем
    setcookie("login", $login, $time+1800);
    setcookie("pass", md5($pass), $time+1800);
    $state = 1;// статус, если 1, тогда пользователь авторизован
      }
    }
  }
}
if($state != 1) {
?>
<form method="post" action="/index.php">
Логин: <input type="text" size="30" name="login"/>
Пароль: <input type="password" name="pass" size="30"/>
<input type="submit" value="Войти"/>
</form>
<a href="/register.php">Регистрация</a>
<?
} else {
  include("pages/index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: а в чем трабл?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Хотите получить фидбэк на написанный код?

Comment: Проблема в том, что не заменяет он ни фига.

Comment: а ошибки какие есть?  $userinfo - вот этот массив вообще где объявлен , где заполняется?

Comment: Нету, просто не изменяет.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) и ini_set('display_errors', 'on') в начале скрипта делали?

Comment: Это весь скрипт обработчика который я выложил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А у Вас $userinfo содержит что то?

запишите запрос некую переменную, выведите её, и посмотрите что не так, но скорее всего - проблема в отсутствии кавычек при указании логина (это же текстовое поле)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money='".$x."' WHERE login='".$userinfo["login"]."';");
```

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: В $userinfo хранятся данные о пользователе.

Comment: Это весь скрипт обработчика который я выложил.

Comment: @cnofss, нам бы var_dump($userinfo) посмотреть

Comment: @Fike, добавил в описание(файл index.php).

Answer (score 0):

login=".$userinfo["login"] на login='".$userinfo['login']."'"
и обрабатывайте все ответы, так проще найти ошибки.

Comment: Не работает

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что в запрос, где UPDATE, надо вместо $userinfo['login'] подставить либо $_POST['login'], либо $_COOKIE['login'], потому что переменная $userinfo определяется ниже.

А еще у вас с запросами что-то не то:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'"; - такой у вас
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='".$login."'"; - такой должен быть
```

Comment: Я уже сам нашел ошибку и решил её. Спасибо, но ваш ответ не правильный.